# Table column to follow image width

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the first column (yellow table cell) to follow the width of its content - which is an image, and the second column (limegreen table cell) to fill the remainder of the table. This is important because when you resize the window vertically, the image is also resized and the text in limegreen cell gets a vertical scroll bar.

I found solutions in which the first column takes the minimum amount of text needed to hold its content (`white-space: nowrap` trick), but it doesn't work with images.

If the table layout is not suitable here, I am open to other suggestions, maybe flexbox?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
 .panel {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   max-height: 800px;
   height: 90%;
   max-width: 1200px;
   width: 60%;

   background-color: gray;
   border: 1px solid red;

   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }

 .fixed1 {
   flex-shrink: 0;

   height: 100px;
   background-color: orange;
 }

 .fixed2 {
   flex-shrink: 0;

   height: 200px;
   background-color: pink;
 }

 .variable {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-shrink: 1;

   background-color: yellow;
 }

 .table-layout {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;

   background-color: green;
 }
.table-layout td {
   vertical-align: top;
 }

 .resizable-image {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
 }
 .resizable-image img {
   width: auto;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .resizable-content {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="fixed1">a</div>
  <div class="variable">
    <table class="table-layout">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: yellow;">
          <div class="resizable-image">
            <img src="https://i.redd.it/1pmsjnk8f1g01.jpg" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100%; background-color: limegreen;">
          <div class="resizable-content">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed2">c</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you just want the yellow background to conform around the width of the image with the `table-layout` to take the remaining space where the yellow was initially?  Are there any limitations on it? I'd recommend flex-box, but that's just because tables are rarely responsive.

Comment: Yeah, I figured flexbox is the way. Honestly, I am not even sure why I started with the table layout. To answer your question: Yes, I want the yellow background gone, so to speak; I want that column to always follow the width of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Table Example:**

You can add `display: contents;` on your `resizable-image` div. This way the div will display the width and height of the contents that are in that parent. For demonstration purposes, I changed your `img` to have a fixed width of `300px` to display the behavior.

Because your image is quite large in size, it overflows out of the content by default, so you can set your image a **fixed-width** of 200, 300, or 400px, basically whatever you want, and you will see the `.variable` expands with it.

```css
.panel {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   max-height: 800px;
   height: 90%;
   max-width: 1200px;
   width: 60%;

   background-color: gray;
   border: 1px solid red;

   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }

 .fixed1 {
   flex-shrink: 0;

   height: 100px;
   background-color: orange;
 }

 .fixed2 {
   flex-shrink: 0;

   height: 200px;
   background-color: pink;
 }

 .variable {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-shrink: 1;

   background-color: yellow;
 }

 .table-layout {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;

   background-color: green;
 }
.table-layout td {
   vertical-align: top;
 }

 .resizable-image {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
   display: contents;
 }
 .resizable-image img {
   width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .resizable-content {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="fixed1">a</div>
  <div class="variable">
    <table class="table-layout">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: yellow;">
          <div class="resizable-image">
            <img src="https://i.redd.it/1pmsjnk8f1g01.jpg" style="display: inline-block;" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100%; background-color: limegreen;">
          <div class="resizable-content">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
            <div>Text</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed2">c</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As mentioned in the comments, you said you were going to proceed with a flex-box layout. I was wondering if you have worked on that at all, if not, I can provide a basic flex-box layout also.

Comment: Hi, the flexbox worked for me. Thanks for the code example in this answer. I'll mark it as solved.